# Display none to block not working with JQuery within sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel

I have built a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9qjm18yx/4/) to demonstrate the whole page as it stands.

To give some context, I am building this page using a Laravel blade template.

Only major issue I can think of that may be causing errors is that I am using an older version of JS V 1.11 to be exact but the slide up works so as far as I can see it should work.

The page has a sidebar that is toggled with the button, when you chose an option the old content should slide up and then the new content slide down. I was hoping to get this working with the js below but can't get it to work, I have stripped the file back to basics and still can't get an error through. Really concerned that its a really simple issue that I haven't twigged as there aren't any JS errors in the console.

```
$(".policy-option").on("click", function(){
  //hide all
  $(".section").slideUp();
  //Show the new div
  var chosen = $(this).attr("id");

  alert(chosen);
  makeDivAppear(chosen);

});

function makeDivAppear(id){
  $("#"+id).slideDown();
}
```

Spent a few hours going through different stack overflow posts trying different techniques. I am aware I don't need the extra function `makeDivAppear` but that was just me doing some extra debug.

Please help!

Comment: I notice that you have 2 elements with same ID...

Comment: Well spotted, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As spotted by [Praveen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1918890/praveen) I was using the same Id for the options in the sidebar as well as the div itself!

Stupid error, well spotted